# Reading events form CSV file in ESPER

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

In ESPER documentation it is mentioned that Esper can process up to 10k to 200k events per second

I am reading Events form CSV file but the maximum limit for events per second is 1000

Example code:

```
CSVInputAdapterSpec spec = new CSVInputAdapterSpec(new      AdapterInputSource(myURL), "PriceEvent");
spec.setEventsPerSec(1000);
InputAdapter inputAdapter = new CSVInputAdapter(epService, spec);
inputAdapter.start();   //method blocks unless engine thread option is set
```

Can someone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The "spec.setEventsPerSec(1000);" sets the target rate at 1k per sec? Try leaving it out?
Also if you want to test performance don't do IO and don't convert from text to data.